# Export YouTube Watch Later Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I've reached the 5000 video Watch Later list limit. So putting aside my hoarding issue, is there a way to export the Watch Later list (preferably with title and link) so that I can continue to add more videos? Maybe to Excel or save to pdf? Is there another option that would allow me to continue to save more videos to my Watch Later list? Thanks!

Comment: What about to [another playlist](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153074/197614)? See if that still works.